# Show $g(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose that $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and differentiable at $x_0 \in (a,b)$. Define

$g(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$

for $x \in (a,b)\setminus \{x_0\}$ and $g(x_0)=f'(x_0)$. Prove that $g$ is continuous on $(a,b)$.

Here is how I have attempted it thus far:

Assume we have $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous on its domain and differentiable at $x_0 \in (a,b)$. Then, we know

$lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=L$

or, in other words, that our limit at $x_0$ exists. We wish to show that $g:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on its domain. Since $f$ is continuous by assumption and, clearly, $x-x_0$ is continuous the only point we need concern ourselves with is $x_0$. Everywhere else we have the difference and quotient of continuous functions where the denominator is non-zero which is also continuous. Since $g(x_0)=f'(x)$ by definition we select $\delta>0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$ and given $\varepsilon>0$ we have

$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-f'(x)\right|=0<\varepsilon$

I am unsure of how to pick our $\delta$ but I am fairly certain all the ideas here are correct. Thanks!

Comment: No $\epsilon$-$\delta$ needed, we have continuity at $x_0$ by definition, since the limit of the difference quotient is $f'(x_0)$, and that's how $g$ is defined at $x_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the following in the specified **order**

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} g(x) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} {{f(x) - f({x_0})} \over {x - {x_0}}} = f'({x_0}) = g({x_0})$$

so $g(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$. In the first equality, I used the definition of $g(x)$. In the second equality, I used the assumption that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$. Finally, in the third one, I again used the definition of $g(x)$.